# UIPopover: UISegmentedControl instead of title

Tags: ios, uipopover

I have a Popover and the title @"Title". Is it possible to have UISegmentedControl there, instead of the title? In other words, I want a popover which has a segmentedcontrol in the middle of header. How to?

The content of popover is UITableViewController, it is inside a UINavigationController, and I present it via presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UISegmentedControl *sc = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil] autorelease];
// config the control

UIBarButtonItem *scItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sc] autorelease];

// add the segmented control, instead of the UILabel title
self.navigationItem.titleView = scItem.customView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIToolbar` at the top of the popover view. Either in interface builder, or programatically, insert a `UISegmentedControl` with flexible space either side of it. For example:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                   target:nil
                                                                                   action:nil];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Segment 1", @"Segment 2", nil]];
UIBarButtonItem *segmentedBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];

[self.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, segmentedBarButton, flexibleSpace]];
```